# How can I get either the selected row or a collection of rows in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I want to get either the selected ROW or a collection of all the rows in the grid (even the non-rendered ones). I want the ngRow objects not the item behind them, in order to locate the row in the DOM. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the non-rendered rows is going to require some extra work.  You'll need to save everything that's selected in the grid to a local variable when you page or whatever you're doing that doesn't have the originally selected rows anymore.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'data',
    selectedItems: $scope.selections,
    afterSelectionChange:function() {
        //save selections to a service here
    },
};
```

I think you can do the second one differently and more correctly another way, what do you need to get the row ids for?

You can submit the row object by simply passing in "row" which is the overall object for each row in the grid. You'll have have to do this on each of the rows of course though using a template.